# Looking for help understanding the proof behind Schnirelmann Theorem: $d(A+B) \ge d(A) + d(B) - d(A)d(B)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am trying to understand the proof by Gelfond & Linnik that:

$$d(A+B) \ge d(A) + d(B) - d(A)d(B)$$

Here's what I understand:

Let $A$, $B$ be infinite sequences of integers starting with $0$ where $0 < a_1 < a_2 < \dots$ and $0 < b_1 < b_2 < \dots$

Let $C$ be an infinite sequence of integers such that $C = A + B$

Let $A(n)$, $B(n)$, $C(n)$ be the number of integers in the sequence less than or equal to $n$ not including $0$.

Let $a_k$, $a_{k+1}$ be two adjacent integers in the sequence $A$.  If there is any numbers in between, then they are:

$$a_k + 1, a_k + 2, \dots, a_k + l = a_{k+1}-1$$

So, it follows that the count of numbers in between $a_k$ and $a_{k+1}$ that are found in $C$ is $B(l)$.

From this observation, Gelfond & Linnik conclude:

$$C(n) \ge A(n) + \sum_{(l)}B(l)$$

where the "sum is taken over the intervals between the numbers of the form $a_k$ and $a_{k+1}$."

I am confused about what the above means?

I am also confused about the observations that follow:

Gelfond & Linnik observe that: $B(l) \ge d(B)*l$ where $d(B)$ is the density of $B$ defined as:

$$d(B) = \inf_{n} \frac{B(n)}{n}$$

I am unclear how $l$ can be taken from each interval $a_k$ and $a_{k+1}$ in one case and then be used later as a single value.  What does $l$ equal?

Further below, Gelfond & Linnik note that $\sum{l} = (n - A(n))$

I would appreciate it if someone could explain what $\sum_{(l)} {B(l)}$ means and explain how it is clear that $\sum(l) = (n - A(n))$.

Comment: It is starting to get clearer.  If $l$ is the count of numbers in between $a_k$ and $a_{k+1}$, then I can see that $\sum{l} = (n - A(n))$ but then shouldn't $C(n) = A(n) + \sum_{(l)}{B(l)}$?

Comment: I've attempted to [reconstruct the proof](http://elementarymethodsanalyticnumbertheory.blogspot.com/2013/11/theorem-1.html) as clearly as I can.  I think that my understanding is correct.  Please let me know if I got anything wrong.  Thanks!